# 404 when loading static files like .css o .js from webroot folder in after building project - Release

Tags: c#, .net, file, razor, static

When I'm starting the project in Release mode by running the .dll file (dotnet publish --configuration Release) I only get 404 at loading of all my .css and .js files. If I run it in Development mode without building it, all files are loading without any problems.

I've made a new project to try it out. I've put             app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

~ at all href's

All .css and .js files are in wwwroot folder.